# Katalon web recorder erreur IOS

Tags: java, ios, katalon

What could be causing the "unknown server cannot find chrome binary" error when using Katalon Studio's web recorder to record test cases on iOS Ventura 13.4, while using JDK 1.8? Can anyone provide assistance with this issue, please?

same problem when i change navigateur

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.